# Is this graph ergodic?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I had a long discussion with a friend of mine about if this simple graph is ergodic. I think it is because every state can be reached in an non-endless number of steps. My friend argues that it is not because there are no state transitions from each node to itself. Is that required? If somebody has a few examples for each case, it would perhaps helps me to understand it better --- other than the pure math...

```
A <----> B
```

Here the transition matrix:

```
     A    B
 A  0.0  1.0
 B  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: What's the corresponding transition matrix? Without the transition matrix it is not possible to answer your question. (And no, it is *not* required that there are transitions from each node to itself.)

Comment: I added it to the quesiton.

Comment: Given that A can only be reached by a periodic move over B, he argues, it is periodic and therefore not ergodic...

Comment: What's the definition of an ergodic graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your friend is right, the chain is *not* ergodic. By definition, a Markov chain with transition matrix $P$ is ergodic if there exists $n \geq 1$ such that

$$P^n > 0. \tag{1}$$

A direct calculation shows that $P^n$ either equals $P$ or

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

for any $n \geq 1$. This means that $(1)$ doesn't hold true for any $n \geq 1$.

*Intuition:* Ergodic means that we can find $n \geq 1$ such that $\mathbb{P}^i(X_n = j)>0$ for any two states $i,j$, i.e. if the process starts at $X_0=i$ it reaches $j$ in $n$ steps with probability $>0$. In the given example, this is not satisfied. For example, for $i=A$, we have either $\mathbb{P}^A(X_n = A)=0$ (if $n$ is odd) or $\mathbb{P}^A(X_n=B)=0$ (if $n$ is even).

**Remark:** A weaker notion is the so-called "irreducibility" of a Markov chain; then, it is only required that $\mathbb{P}^i(X_n = j)>0$ for some $n$ which may depend on $i$ and $j$. It is not difficult to see that the given Markov chain is irreducible (because, as you say, "every state can be reached in an non-endless number of steps").

Answer (score 0):

Ergodic Markov chains are in places explicitly defined as being irreducible and *aperiodic*, for example in [Randall, Dana. "Rapidly mixing Markov chains with applications in computer science and physics." Computing in Science & Engineering 8.2 (2006): 30-41.](http://128.148.32.110/courses/csci2820/papers/rapidly_mixing_mc.pdf)

> Definition 1: A Markov chain is ergodic if it is
>
> 1. irreducible, that is, for all $x, y \in \Omega$, there is a
>    $t$ such that $P_t(x, y) > 0$, and
> 2. aperiodic, that is, for all $x, y \in \Omega$, $\gcd\{t: P_t(x, y)
>    > 0\} = 1$, where $\gcd$ is the greatest common
>    divider.